# what dlls do i need

Tags: .net, visual-studio, silverlight

i have a silverlight project

it references other dlls

in the bin folder it looks like this

myproject.dll
otherproject.dll
otherdll.dll

If I want to reference my project from another project what dlls do i need to copy over?

Can i just copy over the myproject.dll or will it break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project will need all the libraries. I think the other DLLs will be automatically copied to your bin directory if you add the reference to myproject.dll through Visual Studio, but don't hold me to that.

Answer (score 0):

It will break, unless otherproject.dll and otherdll.dll are in the GAC.

The system needs to be able to locate all references.

Comment: This is correct except for the mention of the GAC. Silverlight does not use the GAC, so all of the assemblies must be copied so that they end up in the .xap package.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referencing those libraries then those dll's will be added to xap package files when you build the project. You don't need to add them manually.

Only one xap file is created per one hosted silverlight solution. If you have multiple projects in a solution, only one xap will be built which will contain everything(the assemblies) you used or references.